# Torch widget in ICS

Tags: android, widget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Does anyone managed to create a widget that turns on and off the camera led on nexus s or galaxy nexus? I was able to do so on my activity using a surfaceView but i'm not been able to in a widget. Can anyone post here a sample, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution.
Create a dummy invisible activity with a surfaceView. 
Call that activity and after surfaceView is created kill the actitivy as soon as possible.

Comment: How did you do this? It's not working for me. LED is not flashing up when I have finish(); somewhere in my invisible activity...